# Remove attachments from formit emails in modX

Tags: email-attachments, modx-revolution, formit

Formit automatically collects the data of all your fields and places them in an email whenever you use the "email" hook. However, I want the email to be sent with all the field data but I want to leave out the attachments.
I was able to disable the attachments within the email hook itself but this will be overwritten whenever you update Formit.

Is there a way to remove the attachments or disable them just for the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain hooks in FormIt extra one after another like `... &hooks = 'spam,customhook,email,redirect' ...`. So, just from the top of my head, I would place a [custom](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/formit/formit.tutorials-and-examples/formit.examples.custom-hook) hook before `email` hook. The custom one does some job with submitted files (for example, uploads them to some folder) and then unsets/removes the corresponding fields as if the files were not uploaded and the corresponding fields didn't even exist so that the `email` hook can send emails afterwards w/o the attachments.

Comment: This is exactly what I did but forgot to add it as the answer. Your solution works.